# Swift protocol doesn't work

Tags: swift, protocols

[Why can't convert [HomeADItem] to [ADItem]?  what's the matter? ]

if i mark the ADItem protocol with @objc, modify the HomeADItem super class to NSObject, that's work.  who can help me, thank advance!

```
protocol ADItem {
    var name: String { get }
    var id: String { get }
}

class ADScrollView: UIView {
    class func viewWithframe(frame: CGRect, items: [ADItem]) {}
}

struct HomeADItem: ADItem {
    let name: String
    let id: String
    init(name: String, id: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}

let items = [
    HomeADItem(name: "test1", id: "1"),
    HomeADItem(name: "test2", id: "2")
]

ADScrollView.viewWithframe(CGRectZero, items: items)
```

Comment: please add a snippet of your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift does not automatically infer the type of [HomeADItem] as [ADItem]. Giving it an explicit annotation should fix your problem.

```
let items: [ADItem] = [
    HomeADItem(name: "test1", id: "1"),
    HomeADItem(name: "test2", id: "2")
]
ADScrollView.viewWithframe(CGRectZero, items: items)
```

Comment: Swift has no trouble inferring the type. The type is inferred to `HomeADItem` because `items` contains `HomeADItem` objects. The fact that this type conforms to `ADItem` is not relevant to the compiler here.  *Conforming* doesn't mean *inheriting* so you have to cast explicitly.

Comment: Yea, that was sloppy wording. Thank you.

Comment: @Pyroh I always thought complier can infer the items to [ADItem], thanks